# how to properly clear a WebGL context and all related GPU memory?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I am facing the following issue if I kept a run on a application that runs on a browser running WebGL : "**Rats, WebGL hit a snag!**" .
I am already clearing the textures, framebuffers, programs, buffers and making canvas height and width to 1.

Here's what I am doing :

`

```
var gl = this.gl;
 if(!gl) {
    return;
 }

//delete program
gl.deleteProgram(this.program);

var numTextureUnits = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS);
for (var unit = 0; unit < numTextureUnits; ++unit) {
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, null);
}

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

gl.deleteTexture(this.texture);
gl.deleteTexture(this.textures[0]);
gl.deleteTexture(this.textures[1]);
gl.deleteFramebuffer(this.framebuffers[0]);
gl.deleteFramebuffer(this.framebuffers[1]);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.deleteBuffer(this.vertexBuffer);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textureBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.deleteBuffer(this.textureBuffer);

var buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
var numAttributes = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS);
for (var attrib = 0; attrib < numAttributes; ++attrib) {
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrib, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}
gl.canvas.width = 1;
gl.canvas.height = 1;
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`
```

Steps to reproduce :
1)Open google chrome

2)Run the app(can't give link as it is not yet hosted , apologies!!! :( )

3)Open Chrome task manager and check GPU memory, what I see is it increases drastically as I keep adding new image after clearing and deleting the canvas and adding a new canvas and new context.

Another strange issue/observation is the GPU Memory goes until 25 GB but my GPU has a memory of 2GB only

Comment: Some other part of your code you didn't post has a leak.

Comment: No, this is the only method content where I am deleting the webgl related objects, otherwise other parts are mostly creating programs, assign texture, bind buffer , etc..